# Is there a way to get messages from reply queue after restart of the producer in spring-amqp

Tags: spring-amqp

So my scenario is the following:

- Producer will send a message to a queue using AsyncRabbitTemplate#sendAndReceive
- Consumer will proccess the message and send a reply to the reply queue
  so until now everything will work fine when the producer is up and running. The message from the reply queue will be received and everything is ok.

But when the producer is going down before all replies have been received there is no way to get them later. All pending replies will produce a warning "No pending reply - perhaps timed out:". I totally understand why this is happening when I look at the code. 
Is there no way to have an persistent store of the information of incoming reply messages? Am I doing something comepletely wrong or is it just not possible to cover my use case with spring-amqp?

So the question is what is the best way to receive replies from a fixed reply queue after a restart of the producer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not currently any support for persisting pending reply information; typically with request/reply scenarios, if the requestor dies the reply makes no sense. But I can see there are scenarios where that might not be the case.

Instead of using the async template, you could simply use the `RabbitTemplate` `send()` and use a listener container configured to handle and route the replies.

You would need to do your own request/reply correlation (e.g. with the `correlationId` header), persisting the pending reply correlations someplace.

[Spring Integration provides a `Metadatastore` abstraction](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#metadata-store) with several implementations which might be suitable.